# Return all the employees whose salary is greater than the average salary within their respective departments

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Return all the employees whose salary is greater than the average salary within their respective departments

Comment: Have you tried something to solve the problem? Always post data as text not image.

Comment: You've tagged this for two different databases- Oracle and MySQL.  Which one are you actually using?  Based on the table, I'm guessing you're using Oracle and you're using the `emp` table in the `scott` schema.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow @BABU. Have a look [there](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on guidelines how to ask a question on stackoverflow. FYI, it's not a homework writing service.

Comment: i am using mysql

Comment: Just as a hint for your own first tries: Select `deptno` and the `AVG` (average) of the department's salaries, `GROUP`ing `BY deptno`, as a subquery, and `JOIN` this `ON` the table itself – having added the average salary to the table you then can simply select conditionaly (`WHERE sal > average`).

Answer (score 0):

By Joining to a subquery that calculates the average salary per department

```
select empno, ename, sal, avg_dept_sal, emp.deptno
from employees as emp
join (
  select deptno
  , avg(sal) as avg_dept_sal 
  from employees
  group by deptno
) d on d.deptno = emp.deptno
where sal > avg_dept_sal
```